# How to use JerseyClient in a JAX-RS resource in thread-safe manner

Tags: java, multithreading, jersey, jax-rs

in the following `UserResource` class:

```
public class UserResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/users")
    public void createUser() {
        //JerseyClient is needed to send a REST request to another RESTful service
    }
}
```

`JerseyClient` is needed to send request to another RESTful API as mentioned in the comment.

As in the same time there might be multiple threads calling this `UserResource`, the `JerseyClient` probably should be initialized in each call per thread to be thread-safe. However, the [`JAX-RS Client`](https://jax-rs.github.io/apidocs/2.1/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html?is-external=true) mentioned

> Clients are heavy-weight objects that manage the client-side communication infrastructure. Initialization as well as disposal of a Client instance may be a rather expensive operation. It is therefore advised to construct only a small number of Client instances in the application. Client instances must be properly closed before being disposed to avoid leaking resources.

Based on the documentation, it is probably **expensive** to initialize the `JerseyClient` inside the `createUser` body, and thus bring about the performance issue.

**Question: How to optimize the amount of `JerseyClient` instances efficiently in thread-safe manner?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough if you instantiate your `Client` as a class field, as the `Client` class is thread-safe.

The [Jersey documentation](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-documentation/2.0/jersey-documentation-2.0-user-guide.pdf) says:

> Client  instances  are  expensive  resources.  It  is  recommended  a 
>   configured  instance  is  reused  for  thecreation  of  Web 
>   resources.  The  creation  of  Web  resources,  the  building  of 
>   requests  and  receiving  ofresponses are guaranteed to be thread
>   safe. Thus a Client instance and WebResource instances maybe shared
>   between multiple threads.

Comment: Don't try to reconfigure the client from different threads. Instead configure the WebTargets the you get from the client. And configuration on the client that will never change can be left on the client. Configuration, meaning the setting of properties and registering of providers. These can be don't on bot the client and the WebTarget.